# Get the input value of the last input field using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there a way to get the last value of input text fields inside the `menus` class?

The values are dynamic and the number of input fields are also dynamic.In this example we have 4 input fields inside the `menus` class and the last value I want to get is 4.

```
<p class="menus">
    <input type="text" name="test" class="test" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="test" class="test" value="2">
    <input type="text" name="test" class="test" value="3">
    <input type="text" name="test" class="test" value="4">
</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. It's also well-worth your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end; only takes 1-2 hours. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: `var last_value = $('.menus input').last().val();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery [**last-child-selector**](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)

```js
function getValue() {

  console.log($(".menus input:last-child").val())


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="menus">
  <input type="text" name="test" class="test" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="test" class="test" value="2">
  <input type="text" name="test" class="test" value="3">
  <input type="text" name="test" class="test" value="4">
</p>

<button type="button" onclick="getValue()">Get Value</button>
```